# T-SQL List which tables/columns have rules bound to them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rules

I have an old SQL Sever database with some rules defined. I can get a list of the rules using:

```
select name
from sys.objects so
where so.type_desc = 'rule'
```

I'm trying to delete each of these rules individually using the following statement:

```
DROP RULE [dbo].[my_rule]
```

But I'm getting the following error message:-

> Msg 3716, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The rule 'dbo.my_rule' cannot be dropped because it is bound to one or more column.

What I need is a T-SQL query to inspect the system tables to give me a list of the columns my rule(s) are bound to. Thanks.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 2):

> *What I need is a T-SQL query to inspect the system tables to give me a list of the columns my rule(s) are bound to.*

You could use `sys.columns`:

```
┌────────────────┬───────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  Column name   │ Data type │                  Description                   │
├────────────────┼───────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ rule_object_id │ int       │ ID of the stand-alone rule bound to the column │
│                │           │ by using sys.sp_bindrule.                      │
│                │           │ 0 = No stand-alone rule.                       │
│                │           │ For column-level CHECK constraints             │
└────────────────┴───────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o
  ON o.type_desc = 'RULE'
 AND c.rule_object_id = o.object_id;
```

Comment: Hi if we like to extract which colums in which tables have rules , what is suitable query for it?